# yum install subversion1.4.3

Tags: linux, svn, fedora

How can I reach/install an old subversion package (v1.4.3) without build any sources ?

In fact, the distrib I use is not a FC1 but a "Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 5)".

Do you know some "subversion binaries repositories" where such a configuration may be available for download ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the [RHEL 4 RPM for Subversion 1.4.3](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/subversion/subversion-1.4.3-0.1.el4.rf.i386.rpm) from the [DAG](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/) RPM repository.  The repository web site has a [FAQ](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B4) on configuring Yum for access.

Comment: default svn package for FC1 is 1.4.3 is very interesting, thanks.

Comment: Have DAG it is not nice only, It's a must.
Thanks